# TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable (Error with delete_one)

Tags: python, mongodb, collections, runtime-error, delete-row

This code was working perfectly. It accesses a collection of the Mongo database, extracts the data and deletes the oldest data. However, since a week ago, although I can access the data, filter and display them, I can not delete them because it tells me that `delete_one` is not a method of "Collection" The database is active (It uses a docker-compose) and, as I said, is that you can access the data and every minute that passes new data (Documents in this case) are added.

```
with MongoClient(MONGODB_URI) as client:  # MongoDB
    db = client['twitter_raw']

    tweets_collection = db['tweets_venezuela']

    # number of documents in the collection
    mydoc = tweets_collection.find().count()
    print("The number of documents in collection : ", mydoc) 
    print(tweets_collection)

    #tweets_collection.delete_one({'created_at':"2022-02-16 04:12:22"})
    # print(tweets_collection.find_one())
    for row in tweets_collection.find({}):
        fecha = row["created_at"]
        if(str(fecha) < "2022-02-17 04:12:22"):
            tweets_collection.delete_one({'created_at':fecha})
        else:
            print(fecha)
```

Does anyone know what could be going on? It's quite rare and I can't find anything on the internet.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use it instead "tweets_collection.delete_one({'created_at':fecha})" this "tweets_collection.deleteOne({'created_at':fecha})"